# Lower Bound Scala

Tags: java, scala

```
  class Animal
  class Cat extends Animal
  class Dog extends Animal
```

Upper bound

```
  class CageUP[A <: Animal](animal: A)
```

Lower bound

```
  class CageLB[A >: Animal](animal: A)
```

As per the upper bound definition, it can accept A must be either same as Animal or Sub-Type of Animal.

```
  val cageup = new CageUP(new Dog)
```

As per the lower bound definition, it can accept A must be either same as Animal or Super-Type of Animal.

```
  val cagelb = new CageLB(new Dog)
```

Why lower bound is accepting and compiling even dog instance is passed, which is not a supertype of Animal.

Comment: Because Liskvo, `new Dog` is upcasted to the compiler to be of type `Animal`, you can never forbid this to happen, this is the core principle behind subtyping. Actually, I believe _(I may be wrong)_ that a lower bound on an invariant and covariant _(not sure if contravariant would make a difference)_ generic does nothing, lower bounds are useful for when you need to use a covariant generic on a contravariant position, typical example `prepend` on `List`.

Comment: You can try replacing `class CageLB[A >: Animal](animal: A)` with `class CageLB[A](animal: A)(implicit ev: Animal <:< A)`. Then `new CageLB(new Dog)` shouldn't compile.

Comment: https://blog.bruchez.name/2015/11/generalized-type-constraints-in-scala.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type bounds effect methods at both the call site and the definition site, sometimes in surprising ways.

Let's set up a type hierarchy.

```
class Base             {val base = 'B'}
class Mid extends Base {val mid  = 'M'}
class End extends Mid  {val end  = 'E'}
```

Now let's start with the more common upper bounding.

```
def f[T <: Mid](t:T):Int = {
  val x = t.base
  val y = t.mid
//val z = t.end  <--won't compile
  42
}
//f(new Base)  <--doesn't conform to bounds
f(new Mid)  //OK  
f(new End)  //OK, promoted to Mid in the f() code
```

As expected, there is no `t.end` because that's not a part of type `Mid`, and you can't invoke it with type `Base` because that won't have the `mid` member expected in every type `Mid`.

Now let's flip it to lower bounding.

```
def f[T >: Mid](t:T):Int = {
//val x = t.base <--won't compile
//val y = t.mid  <--won't compile
//val z = t.end  <--won't compile
  42
}
f(new Base)  //OK
f(new Mid)   //OK
f(new End)   //OK
f(List(9))   //OK!!
```

As you can see, a received parameter with no upper bound isn't terribly useful because the compiler sees that it *might* be type `Mid`, but it *might* be type `Any`, and since anything and everything can be promoted to type `Any` then anything is permitted at the call site but almost nothing is known about it at the method definition site.